# how to get icons to toggle alongside <li> on a click event

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to toggle a list item to show. when it is clicked I want a tick icon to toggle with the click. It works with 1 `<li>` item, but when I add another and click that one, the first tick disappears.

How can I get the first tick to remain after the second one is clicked? This is a DOM specific exercise.

I am first setting up an event listener for submit for my form. On submit I am creating a div and an li. Then on click of the li I am adding the icon.

**html:**

```
<div class='body-container'>
    <p class="subtitle">Please add an item</p>

    <form id="myForm" class='form'>
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Items</h2>
    <div>
        <ol class="item">

        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
//grab the target from the form submission
const myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');
const i = document.createElement('i')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const value = event.target[0].value;
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  li.classList.add('test');

  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.classList.toggle('strike');
    div.appendChild(i);
    i.classList.toggle('fas');
    i.classList.toggle('fa-check');
  })

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
  div.appendChild(li)
  ol.appendChild(div)    
})
```

At the moment when I tick the second item the ticks from both li's disappear

Comment: user10045300 you have to add an id to li element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to achieve it, your code was almost right

```
const myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const value = event.target[0].value;
const li = document.createElement('li');
const div = document.createElement('div');
const i = document.createElement('i');
li.id = `item-${new Date().getTime()}`
li.classList.add('test');

li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.classList.toggle('strike');
    div.appendChild(i);
    i.classList.toggle('fas');
    i.classList.toggle('fa-check');
})

    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
    div.appendChild(li)
    ol.appendChild(div)    
})
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks. Would you mind explaining the li.id = `item-${new Date().getTime()}` part? Thanks again

Comment: sure, it's just to generate a random id/timestamp to prevent of having duplicated itens on DOM Tree

Answer (score 1):

Hi Evandro Cavalcate Santos, I was thinking to just move the line

```
const i = document.createElement('i')
```

to the myForm eventListener as you did, because it was created with a global scope and each div would refer to that same global 'i'.
I don't think the 'id' is necessary on each li. Let me know.
Thanks

```js
//grab the target from the form submission
const myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');


myForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const value = event.target[0].value;
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const i = document.createElement('i')
  li.classList.add('test');
  

  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.classList.toggle('strike');
    div.appendChild(i);
    i.classList.toggle('fas');
    i.classList.toggle('fa-check');
  })

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
  div.appendChild(li)
  ol.appendChild(div)    
  
})
```

```css
i.fas:after{
  content: "X"
}
.strike{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='body-container'>
    <p class="subtitle">Please add an item</p>

    <form id="myForm" class='form'>
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Items</h2>
    <div>
        <ol class="item">

        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```